# Java Selenium WebDriver Can't find form field

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm testing a registration page and I've tried name, xpath, id, class and nothing seems to work.

here is my selenium code

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("pushMenu")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement l = driver.findElement(By.name("name"));
```

and here is the form tag I'm trying to access

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="">
```

explicit wait attempt code:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("name")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("name")).sendKeys("Testing100");
```

Comment: can you share your error stack trace.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"name"}

Comment: did you try explicit wait?

Comment: No I did not try that

Comment: Check whether it is in iframe, because your locator seems to be correct and it should not throw NoSuchElementException.

Comment: I'm not using iframe, should I be using it?

Comment: I'm new to using selenium.

Comment: I gave explicit wait a try and it still wasn't able to find the form field.

Comment: try to replicate this on a public URL and that should be easy to resolve

Answer (score 0):

in HTML u shared there is no name tag.
so try by.linktext("Manager")

Comment: Try with Sleenium iDe. what locator value does it suggest. Also check if HTML for register form falls in some iframe, if yes then u need to handle that

Answer (score 0):

Please check the time specified in the wait is sufficient for the element to load completely.
OR
Use different locators like `cssSelector` if name, id(if present) is not working.

```
CssSelector example
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[name='name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the form field, use

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']"));

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the issue of accessing the element after implicit/explicit wait, then try putting a screenshot before you access the element and see if the element is present on the page or not.